# Non-constexpr function's use in constexpr constructor is valid

Tags: c++, stdvector, compile-time

The following is valid in gcc 4.8:

```
class Value {
    private:
        static std::vector<float> compile_time_vector;
        const bool compile_time_bool;

        static bool f(void) {
            compile_time_vector.push_back(2.3);

            return true;
        }

    public:
        template <typename type_t>
        constexpr Value(const type_t& value): compile_time_bool(f()) {}
};
```

std::vector isn't designed to work at compile time, so exactly what kind of code is this generating?  I've used the class to make sure it isn't optimized out.

Comment: It also works with clang 3.3.

Comment: Seems to me like this could be a bug around the fact that templates don't get instantiated until they're required. If you use the class in a `static_assert()` it does fail. I imagine you used it in a runtime context. However I think it should have complained about the `constexpr` being there since that constructor is never a constant expression.

Comment: @mpark Damn, I was really hoping that I could use std::vector as a compile-time list of objects... is there anything that does that?

Comment: You could use `std::array<>` or `std::tuple<>` if your container doesn't have to be dynamically sized and such. I don't believe there's a way to perform `std::vector<>`-like operations currently during compile-time.

Comment: @Mpark I agree. See what happens if you try `constexpr std::initializer_list<Value> test = { Value(int()) };`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ill-formed, but no diagnostic is required. The problem is that `f()` in `constexpr Value(const type_t& value): compile_time_bool(f())` may not appear in a constant expression for *any* template argument. But consider:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

bool foo(A);
constexpr bool foo(B) { return {}; }

template<class T>
constexpr bool bar(T p) { return foo(p); }
```

Here, the `constexpr`ness of `bar` depends on the template argument. Therefore:

```
constexpr A a{};
constexpr B b{};

//constexpr auto ba {bar(a)};  // error
constexpr auto ba {bar(b)};    // fine
auto ba2 {bar(a)};             // fine
```

A function template marked as `constexpr` can produce `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` specializations, depending on the template arguments.

It is probably hard or impossible to check if a function template is not `constexpr` for any set of template arguments (in the OP's case, it could be possible to see that as `f()` unambiguously refers to `Value::f`). Therefore, no diagnostic is required.

---

The relevant paragraph is [dcl.constexpr]/6:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, that specialization is not a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor. [*Note:* If the function is a member function it will still be const as described below. — *end note* ] If no specialization of the template would
>   yield a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

N.B. the `const` thing will be lifted in C++1y, so better mark member functions (not ctors, obviously) both as both `constexpr` and `const`.

---

Effectively, the program has UB. But once you instantiate the ctor in a context that requires a constant expression, your compiler should complain -- as does clang++3.4

Both compilers seem to accept your program if you use the ctor in a context where a constant expression is not required. I'd say that's an extension, but it's as hard to issue a warning in this case ("extension used, nonportable code") as to diagnose the program is ill-formed in the first place.

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect compilers to detect this in general -- determining whether an arbitrary `constexpr` function can produce a constant expression is equivalent to the halting problem. Also, the relevant wording in *[dcl.constexpr]p6* has been [changed significantly by C++11 bugfixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1358).